# Unit test method that uses the flask.request with PyTest

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, pytest

Is it possible to write a unit test (PyTest) to cover a only a method that uses the `flask.request` as in the example below?

```py
api = flask.Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def do_stuff():
    a, b, c = get_params()
    return jsonify(a=a, b=b, c=c)

def get_params():
   data = flask.request.get_json()
   a = data('param_a')
   b = data('param_b')
   c = data('param_c')
```

Or the only way to test `get_params` is through the `do_stuff` pytestfixture?

I have tried to directly call the `get_params` method but cannot work out what/how to actually pass some input as a request:

```py
import example.api

def test_get_params_method(input, expected_output):
    example.api.get_params()
    # assert input == expected_output ?
```

**Update**:

```py
# app.py
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it with the `Blueprint` but you can do it with the application itself and [test_request_context()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/#other-testing-tricks) manager which sets up `flask.request` and thus allows you to simulate an incoming request:

```py
from app import app
from example import get_params

def test_get_params_method(input, expected_output):
    with app.test_request_context('/'):
        get_params()
```

Check out the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.test_request_context) but for your example you probably want to pass `data` argument to the context manager.

Comment: Very useful - had no idea about the `test_request_context()`. Could you please clarify what you mean with `from application import app`?

Comment: Well, don't you create somewhere a `Flask()` instance (that's what I mean by `app`) to which you register the blueprint? Because `test_request_context()` is a method of a `Flask` instance. However, maybe you can just do with `Flask(__name__).test_request_context('/'):`. I'm not sure though.